# Scapy sometimes does not send a packet. Even the crafted packet is not captured on wireshark. (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am using a very simple scapy code to send a dns packet to 8.8.8.8:

```
from scapy.all import IP,DNS,DNSQR,UDP,sendp,Ether,send

dns_req = IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP(sport=6900,dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="www.google.com", qtype="A"))

send(dns_req)
```

I ran this exact code just a few days ago and could receive the reply. But now when I am trying it again, it is not working. Wireshark doesn't even show the crafted packet. I am using windows 10.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? `it is not working` doesn't give us any context on how to help you. So, please paste in the error you are getting with the question.

Comment: @kite that is the problem. I am not getting any errors. Infact, scapy shows that the packet was sent but I am not able to capture any responses in wireshark nor can I capture the crafted packet.

Comment: As the code works properly in a Ubuntu desktop with disabled firewall and root permissions. I guess this might be an issue with the windows firewall blocking the request. So, to debug you might need to disable the firewall and try sending the request and re-enable your firewall when debugging is finished.